# Como compactar diretório exceto uma pasta específica via SSH com comando zip?

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, compressão

Eu tenho que compactar todos os arquivos e diretórios do diretório **public_html** exceto **var** que tem mais de 60GB. Como posso executar essa operação via **SSH** com comando `zip`? Vi algumas formas com comandos diferentes **tar** e outros mas preciso executar essa operação com comando `zip`.

> Eu quero só compactar sem o **var** e não apagá-lo da hospedagem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Procurando no `man zip` encontrei a opção `--exclude` ou `-x`, acredito ser isso exatamente o que você precisa.

```
-x files
       --exclude files
              Explicitly exclude the specified files, as in:

                     zip -r foo foo -x \*.o

              which  will  include  the  contents  of foo in foo.zip while excluding all the files that end in .o.  The backslash avoids the shell filename substitution, so that the name
              matching is performed by zip at all directory levels.

              Also possible:

                     zip -r foo foo -x@exclude.lst

              which will include the contents of foo in foo.zip while excluding all the files that match the patterns in the file exclude.lst.

              The long option forms of the above are

                     zip -r foo foo --exclude \*.o

              and

                     zip -r foo foo --exclude @exclude.lst

              Multiple patterns can be specified, as in:

                     zip -r foo foo -x \*.o \*.c

              If there is no space between -x and the pattern, just one value is assumed (no list):

                     zip -r foo foo -x\*.o

              See -i for more on include and exclude.
```

Answer (score 1):

Você terá que executar o comando remotamente, então:

```
ssh usuario@192.168.1.10 -p 2255 'zip backup.zip /public_html --exclude var'
```

o comando pedirá a senha do usuário e pronto, você terá seu arquivo compactado.

Ps.: Obviamente é necessário adaptar o comando ao seu cenário, no caso o -p 2255 é a porta de conexão ao SSH